# Xamarin Android internet connectivity status checking independently of HTTP request or Ping methods

Tags: xamarin.android, status, internet-connection

I can detect internet connectivity status by the HTTP web request, ping or socket methods but I am searching a way that it is done independently of remote server connection. For example, I request a web page like "www.google.com" (or 8.8.8.8) and when the status code of HTTP request is OK then I realize that internet connectivity is OK. But I don't prefer this way in general because if the remote server was down, consequently mentioned methods report the internet is unavailable.

Is there an independent way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Xamarin plugin which does all this stuff for connectivity check.
You can add [Xam.Plugin.Connectivity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity/) nuget package in your Android and Core projects for this.

How to use it:

```
if(CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
    //Connection is available      
}
else
{
    //Connection is not available
}
```

Here is a documentation on it.
https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/

Comment: I am not sure about its architecture. Does it use Web Request to found out internet connectivity is available?

Comment: Here is an android Implementation: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin/blob/master/src/Connectivity.Plugin.Android/ConnectivityImplementation.cs   Looking into it, it seems like, it does not ping any url if you are using "IsConnected" property to check network status. It checks if Device has internet or not. There is a separate method mentioned here which pings the provided url to check if it is reachable or not : https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/PingaHost.html

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me more. Now I can design my own approach or use your mentioned plugin.